# Form with JQuery Serialized Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms

I have created a form with checkboxes. As a user selects requested checkboxes and hits the submit button, it will return values as webpage links. I can get the items to display, but don't know how to properly write the url values using query. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
  <form>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="http://www.google.com" name="check" value="Option 1" id="ch1">
  <label for="ch1">Checkbox 1</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="http://www.yahoo.com"name="check" value="Option 2" id="ch2">
  <label for="ch2">Checkbox 2</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="http://www.weather.com" value="Counseling Services" id="ch3">
  <label for="ch3">Checkbox 3</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="http://www.cnn.com" value="Financial Aid" id="ch4">
  <label for="ch4">Checkbox 4</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="http://www.foxnews.com" value="Fitness and Recreation" id="ch5">
  <label for="ch5">Checkbox 5</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="http://www.gmail.com" value="Health Services" id="ch6">
  <label for="ch6">Checkbox 6</label>
  </form>

  <button>Show Results</button>
  <p>Results:<span id="results"></span></p>

  function showValues() {

  var fields = $( ":input" ).serializeArray();
  $( "#results" ).empty();
  jQuery.each( fields, function( i, id, name ) {
  $( "#results" ).append(' <a href= "input.name" > ' + id.value + " " );
  });
  }

  $( "button" ).click( showValues );
  $( "select" ).change( showValues );
  showValues();
```

[Here is my JFiddle.](http://www.jsfiddle.net/XjZD5)

Comment: Your html is incorrect, you have over a dozen errors in here. You should first ask separately on how you should construct this form and then get into jquery and the event handlers, no javascript is going to work properly for this, what does name="http://www.yahoo.com"name="check" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function showValues() {

    var fields = $(":input").serializeArray();
    $("#results").empty();
    jQuery.each(fields, function (idx, obj) {
        $("#results").append('<a href= "' + obj.name + '" >' + obj.value + "</a>");
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MzpFe/)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help... it worked! I'm really new with Jquery and Javascript, so thanks for helping someone that doesn't really know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Write the url in the value attribute and it will works

The value attribute specifies the value to be sent to a server when a form is submitted

```
<form>
 <br>
  <input type="checkbox"  name="check[]" value="http://www.google.com" id="ch1">
  <label for="ch1">Checkbox 1</label>
  <br/>

   <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="http://www.yahoo.com" id="ch2">
   <label for="ch2">Checkbox 2</label>
  <br/>

  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="http://www.weather.com" id="ch3">
  <label for="ch3">Checkbox 3</label>
  <br/>

  <input type="checkbox"name="check[]" value="http://www.cnn.com" id="ch4">
  <label for="ch4">Checkbox 4</label>
  <br/>

   <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="http://www.foxnews.com" id="ch5">
   <label for="ch5">Checkbox 5</label>
       <br/>

   <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="http://www.gmail.com" id="ch6">
   <label for="ch6">Checkbox 6</label>
      <br/>
</form>
<br/>
<button>Show Results</button>
<p>Results:<span id="results"></span></p>
```

Added brackects to the name to store as array if you will need

[Useful Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)